# Math.random, Javascript. Что-то пошло не так

Tags: javascript, математика, случайные-числа

```
var GoodObj = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
    var trololo = parseInt(a + b);
    GoodObj.lala = trololo;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += a;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += '+';
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += b;
});

function myFunction (){
    var  myTrololo = GoodObj.lala;
    var stop = false;
    if (document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML == myTrololo) {
        alert('right');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('false');
        return stop;
    }
}

function randomInt(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
var param = randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala);
alert(randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala));
```

Здесь GoodObj.lala - сума двух рандомных чисел. Не думаю, что тот кусок кода нужен.
В общем, выводит Nan. В других случаях перемещения переменной или еще чего - что код слишком рекурсивен. Уже совсем запуталась

Comment: Тот кусок кода нужен, так как [если бы он был правильный](https://jsfiddle.net/bm30jfbe/1/), то всё бы работало.

Comment: `выводит Nan` - значит `GoodObj.lala` не число...

Comment: <https://pp.userapi.com/c638629/v638629157/5fe86/iI5FmYrALdo.jpg> Число же

Comment: просто посмотрите что у вас в `GoodObj.lala`, не надо ссылок на картинки, которые у меня еще и не грузятся :)

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не подключен jQuery, а вы пытаетесь делать `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @ MedvedevDev, ну что-то такое:

Comment: @MedvedevDev как ты это понял ?) на картинке что-то есть ?)

Comment: уберите эту конструкцию, либо замените на window.onload = () => { /* code */ }

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, ссылка битая, лишние символы поудаляй просто. [ВОТ](https://pp.userapi.com/c638629/v638629157/5fe86/iI5FmYrALdo.jpg)

Comment: @MedvedevDev у меня всеравно не грузит, видимо изза того что я с Украины :)

Comment: @MedvedevDevНу, во-первых, jQuery подключен. Во-вторых, код вот там,  выше. Можете посмотреть, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var GoodObj = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  var trololo = parseInt(a + b);
  GoodObj.lala = trololo;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += a;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += '+';
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML += b;

  var param = randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala);
  console.log(randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala));
});

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

// этот кусок кода выполняется сразу, тогда, когда инициализация 
// var trololo = parseInt(a + b);
// GoodObj.lala = trololo;
// только после загрузки всего ДОМ дерева
// в итоге GoodObj.lala попросту не существует и ровняется undefined что и дает нам NaN
// просто перенесите в $(document).ready

//var param = randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala);
//console.log(randomInt(14, GoodObj.lala));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="number"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное С:

Comment: @Біпач незачто, в следующий раз сразу давайте весь код, быстрее будет :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych не учите плохому. Давать надо MCVE, а не "весь код".

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы правы :) я чтото на подобе этого и имел в виду.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а что такое MCVE?

Comment: @Біпач [Вот тут почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это иногда сложно сочетать

Comment: @Біпач ничего сложного, надо просто сокращать код пока ошибка продолжает воспроизводиться. К примеру, в вашем коде можно было бы убрать переменные `b` и `trololo`, а также функции `myFunction` и `randomInt`.